# CSS Sprite is squashing rather than cropping

Tags: css, image, sprite

So I am trying to make some images into a sprite. I thought I understood pretty well what I was doing, but then instead of getting 6 different images, I get 1 squashed image 6 times.

Here is my code

```
img.sprite
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-image:url(myimage.jpg) 0 0;
}

img.sprite2
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-image:url(myimage.jpg) -100px 0;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<img class="sprite" src="myimage.jpg" width="1" height="1" />

<img class="sprite2" src="myimage.jpg" width="1" height="1" />
```

When I post this, my image is just squashed so I have 6 images of my sprite being resized and distorted, when I want it to give me a resized image of only a portion. It is not cropping for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your are combining background images with inline images, this will not work. The background image is for use on things such as divs and other page elements.

also in your css you have the position coordinates within the 'background-image' property, this will not work either, it either needs to be in the generic 'background' css property or the specific 'background-position' one.  see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

if you need to use it on inline images try this technique using css clip http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-with-inline-images/

Comment: This is how w3schools had told me how to do it though. See their example for sprites.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_img

What am I doing that is different from their example?

Comment: you are using 'background-image' not 'background', the 'background-image' does not support background-position coordinates